# in R, group columns by column name instead of column number

Tags: r, dataframe, names

In R, is there a way to group a data.frame by colnames instead of the column number?

```
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(replicate(5, sample(c(1:99), 7, rep = TRUE)))

names(df) <- c("alpha","bravo","charlie","delta","echo"); df
```

Normally, I'd group a segment of the data.frame like:

```
df[,2:4]
```

Often in larger datasets with hundreds of columns, it's more difficult to pinpoint the column number.  I'd like to group the columns by using their column name instead of column number.  The following gives an error message, but indicates what I'm trying to do.

```
df[,"bravo":"delta"]
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `dplyr`, we can use the range of column names in `select`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   select(bravo:delta)
#  bravo charlie delta
#1    82      74    37
#2    59       7    34
#3    51      73    89
#4    97      79    44
#5    85      85    79
#6    21      37    33
#7    54      89    84
```

Answer (score 4):

In base R, you can use `which` to return the column index based on name:

```r
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(replicate(5, sample(c(1:99), 7, rep = TRUE)))
names(df) <- c("alpha","bravo","charlie","delta","echo")

df[, which(colnames(df) == "bravo"):which(colnames(df) == "delta")]

#   bravo charlie delta
# 1    66      77    22
# 2    63      50    65
# 3     7      72    13
# 4    21      99    27
# 5    18      38    39
# 6    69      77     2
# 7    39      93    38
```